# set input to empty string or null if it is not filled and save other datas in vue with laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have about seven input field in my newinsight i want some of the input field to be optional either it is field or not the post should be saved to database, i get error 500 if i leave some inputs empty. I have tried an it seems not working can anyone help out. below is my code.

**my controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $insight= new Insight();
    $insight->slug = $request->slug;
    $insight->body = $request->body;
    $insight->head1 = $request->head1;
    $insight->paragraph1 = $request->paragraph1;
    $insight->head2 = $request->head2;
    $insight->paragraph2 = $request->paragraph2;
    $insight->head3 = $request->head3;
    $insight->paragraph3 = $request->paragraph3;
    $insight->head4 = $request->head4;
    $insight->paragraph4 = $request->paragraph4;
    $insight->head5 = $request->head5;
    $insight->paragraph5 = $request->paragraph5;
    $insight->head6 = $request->head6;
    $insight->paragraph6 = $request->paragraph6;
    $insight->head7 = $request->head7;
    $insight->paragraph7 = $request->paragraph7;
    if($request->hasFile('image')){
        $file = $request->file('image');
       $file_name = time(). '.' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
       $file->move(public_path('img/'),$file_name);
       $insight->image = 'img/' . $file_name;
       
    }
  
    $insight->save();
    return response()->json(['message'=>'Saved Successfully'],200); 
}
```

**form**

```
 data() {
        return {
            form: new Form({
             image:null,
             slug:'',
             body: '',
             head1:'',
             paragraph1: '',
             head2:'',
             paragraph2: '',
             head3:'',
             paragraph3: '',
             head4:'',
             paragraph4: '',
             head5:'',
             paragraph5: '',
             head6:'',
             paragraph6: '',
             head7:'',
             paragraph7: '',
            }),
           show: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onChange(e){
           const file = e.target.files[0]
           this.form.image = file
            console.log("selected file", file) 
        },
        submit(){
            this.form.post('/api/insight', {
                transfromRequest: [function(data, headers){
                    return objectToFormData(data)
                }],
                onUploadProgress: e =>{
                    console.log(e,)
                }
            }).then(({data})=>{
                console.log(data)
            })
            console.log(this.form)
             this.form = ''
             this.form.image = ''
        },
```

above is my vue js form

Comment: You have forgotten to add your code :)

Comment: The HTTP status code `500` is a generic error response. It means that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request. Please have a look at API level as API might expecting value from all the fields.

Comment: Please how can i make my api not to expect all fields to be filled or have value before i can submit?

Comment: submit(){
            this.form.post('/api/insight', {
                transfromRequest: [function(data, headers){
                    return objectToFormData(data)
                }],
                onUploadProgress: e =>{
                    console.log(e)
                }
            }).then(({data})=>{
                console.log(data)
            })
            console.log(this.form)
             this.form = ''
             this.form.image = ''
        },

Comment: data() {
        return {
            form: new Form({
             image:null,
             slug:'',
             body: '',
             head1:'',
             paragraph1: '',
             head2:'',
             paragraph2: '',
             head3:'',
             paragraph3: '',
             head4:'',
             paragraph4: '',
             head5:'',
             paragraph5: '',
             head6:'',
             paragraph6: '',
             head7:'',
             paragraph7: '',
            }),
           show: false
        }
    },

Comment: above is the methods and form data objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make fields nullable in database. Then fields will be `NULL` if you doesn't set them.

Migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('insights', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('body')->nullable();
        $table->string('head1')->nullable();
        $table->string('paragraph1')->nullable();
        $table->string('head2')->nullable();
        //...etc
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

And you can do it without errors:

```
public function store() {
    $insight = new Insight();
    $insight->save();
}
```

DB result:

```
mysql> select * from insights;
+----+------+-------+------------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | body | head1 | paragraph1 | head2 | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+------+-------+------------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | NULL | NULL  | NULL       | NULL  | 2022-02-22 07:38:58 | 2022-02-22 07:38:58 |
+----+------+-------+------------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    // validate your compulsory field here.
    $insight= new Insight();

    foreach($request->all() as $key => $value){
      $insight[$key] = $value;
    }

    unset($insight[_token]); // if that's your csrf name

    if($request->hasFile('image')){
        $file = $request->file('image');
       $file_name = time(). '.' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
       $file->move(public_path('img/'),$file_name);
       $insight[image] = 'img/' . $file_name;
       
    }
  
    $insight->save();
    return response()->json(['message'=>'Saved Successfully'],200); 
}
```

Comment: I think the error i am facing is from my vue js form it not posting to database untill i fill all filed and i want to post if the inputs are empty or not except from the image upload . i tried these did'nt work.